# Same responses are received for every request sent from button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, networking, android-networking

The following code is used in the MainActivity:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
Cache cache;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonDiscard = findViewById(R.id.buttonDiscard);

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    requestQueue.start();
    String url ="https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            stringBuilder::append,
            error -> System.out.println("Error occurred"));
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
public void handleDiscardClick(View view){
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
}
```

The issue I am facing is that I am receiving same string response for every click on the button from the url which gives random meal in json format. The only way I can get different string is with every restart of the android app which is definitely not good at all. I tried moving the networking code inside the button function still I am receiving same response. I will highly appreciate if anyone can tell me how to get different response for every click on the button. (Sorry, I am new to android networking)

Comment: Doesn't it happen because you use cache? DiskBasedCache

Comment: Probably. But, moving the cache line anywhere except onCreate() causes crash. :< @Alex.Marynovskyi

Comment: The question is do you need the cache or not? You can disable it by request.setShouldCache(false)

Comment: I don't need cache. I will disable and check if that fix or not. @Alex.Marynovskyi

Comment: I couldn't find request.setShouldCache(false) so, instead, I have used the following line requestQueue = new RequestQueue(new NoCache(), network);
Still same response. @Alex.Marynovskyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the whole code. I wrote the following code in another class and it worked well:

```
public class NetworkController {
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
private final RequestQueue queue;

public StringBuilder getstringBuilder() {
    return stringBuilder;
}

public void setModelFromNetwork() {
    final String url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            response -> {
                try {
                    stringBuilder.append(response.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("JSONException occurred. The error is: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, exception -> System.out.println("Error"));
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public NetworkController(@NonNull final Activity activity) {
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
}
```